# How to get enum value on report

Tags: rdlc

Designation{Admin=1,Manager=2}
Database contains just the digit 1,2.

Now i want to built RDLC Report but the report doesn't show the digit. The report must show the digit across value (for example, 1 for Admin)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using C#?

If so, you want to use Enum.GetNames()
See [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200805023121/http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2007/12/18/117799.aspx) for a code example.

If you need to do it in SQL code, then I agree with simply having a lookup table (although it can be a pain to keep the code enum and DB in sync).

Comment: Thanks your given link is very useful .....I use C# to built report on RDLC ....plz give me some example or link to built on RDLC

Comment: I'm not familliar with RDLC.  How are you passing the enum right now to RDLC?  Can you pass the strings (using Enum.GetNames()) instead of the enum integer values?

Answer (score -1):

Create a table that holds the numeric values and the corresponding text values.  Then create a User Defined Function to return the text value based on the enumerated value you return in the query for the report.  The user defined function can be called in the select statement and will return the text value.